# Select single entry with largest column value from table, where multiple entries have this value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to select all entries from a table with the largest 'duration' values, for a given combination of 'source_id' and 'bands' values, but in the case where this results in multiple entries with equal duration to output only one of these.

Currently I have the query:

```
select source_id, bands, duration
    FROM new_table AS obs
    WHERE
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM new_table AS obs_max
            WHERE (obs_max.source_id = obs.source_id 
            AND obs_max.bands = obs.bands 
            AND obs_max.duration > obs.duration)
        ) = 0
```

As an example of what I'm trying to achieve, for the table:

| source_id | bands | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | test | 3 |
| 12345 | test | 3 |
| 12345 | test | 3 |
| 12345 | test | 2 |
| 54321 | hello | 4 |
| 34521 | world | 5 |

The above code returns the same table without the 4th row - i.e., for the case with source_id = 12345 and bands = test, it returns all values with the maximum duration for that combination, hence returning three entries, all with duration 3. I would like it to return:

| source_id | bands | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | test | 3 |
| 54321 | hello | 4 |
| 34521 | world | 5 |

Comment: Try `select source_id, bands, max(duration) FROM new_table GROUP BY  source_id, bands`

Comment: I can't upvote you because it's a comment and not an answer, but this works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Just a quick note, I had to change `max(duration)` to `max(duration) AS duration` so that the column wasn't renamed, but otherwise that's great.